# Direct2D window black when not in focus

Tags: c++, windows, focus, hwnd, direct2d

I have a Direct2D window which paints fine when in focus; however, when focus moves to another window (same application or another), the entire window goes black. I pinned the issue down to the use of `ID2D1HwndRenderTarget::Clear`. This function is vital to my application as without it, painting becomes rather... weird.

Is there a way an un-focused Direct2D window can paint as normal (note: `WM_PAINT` is being called as usual, as is `Clear`, `BeginPaint`, etc. all without error)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't actually say what you want to accomplish here. I assume you don't want the window to go black, but you should edit this to say what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With my experience with DirectX, if the screen turns back its because DX lost the device it was 'painting' to.  This happens a lot - for instance - when switching between a full-screen DirectX window to another application, and vice-versa.

So what you need to do is re-intialize the DX device so it can resume painting operations.

This might help some more (not my website, but a quick Google search turned it up)

http://www.programmersheaven.com/2/FAQ-DIRECTX-Avoid-task-switching

Answer (score 2):

From MSDN,

```
Handling Device Loss
```

> While your program is running, the
>   graphics device that you are using
>   might become unavailable. For example,
>   the device can be lost if the display
>   resolution changes, or if the user
>   removes the display adapter. If the
>   device is lost, the render target also
>   becomes invalid, along with any
>   device-dependent resources that were
>   associated with the device. Direct2D
>   signals a lost device by returning the
>   error code D2DERR_RECREATE_TARGET from
>   the EndDraw method. If you receive
>   this error code, you must re-create
>   the render target and all
>   device-dependent resources.

Please check the link for more info. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff684174(VS.85).aspx